# Young said it is here to stay

Tags: rebus

Here is an easy rebus:

[image]

Can you find what it is about?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is

> **ROCK AND ROLL MUSIC**

Explanations

> 1. Picture of a **ROCK**
>  2. The **AND** Gate
>  3. The crescent **ROLL**
>  4. [MEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mew_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) from Pokémon
>  5. Picture of someone **SICK**. Hence, *MEW+SICK*=**MUSIC**
>
>  [image]

And the title -

> [*Hey Hey, My My (Into the Black)* - **Neil Young**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hey_Hey,_My_My_(Into_the_Black)) which has a line *Rock N' Roll Is Here To Stay* [image]

Comment: Surely this is not the correct song title.

Comment: @LeppyR64-Yeah. I thought to put the relevant lines only. :) Updated the right title.

Comment: I found the solution in like 5 seconds lol... but that was still too slow. good job little ninja.